# How to show that a quotient ring is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $M_3(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ be the ring of $3\times 3$-matrices over the field $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and let $R$ be the commutative subring of $M_3(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ with multiplicative identity, $$R=\bigg\{
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     a & b & c \\
>     0 & a & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & a
>   \end{bmatrix}
> \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_5\bigg\}
> $$
> Let $$I =\bigg\{
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     0 & b & c \\
>     0 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 0
>   \end{bmatrix}
> \mid b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_5\bigg\}
> $$ be an ideal in $R$.

> I have to show that the quotient ring $R/I$ is a field.

My approach: since $R/I$ is a quotient ring, I need to show that $R/I$ is a commutative division ring.

The commutative part is just showing that any two elements $R_1/I = \bigg(
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1 & b_1+b & c_1+c \\
    0   & a_1   & 0 \\
    0   & o     & a_1
  \end{bmatrix}
|a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_5\bigg)
$ and

$R_2/I = \bigg(
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_2 & b_2+b & c_2+c \\
    0   & a_2   & 0 \\
    0   & o     & a_2
  \end{bmatrix}
|a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_5\bigg)
\in R/I$ commute, ie $R_1/I*R_2/I=R_2/I*R_1/I$, right?

But showing that every non-zero element is a unit is a bit tougher.

With the multiplicative id $ = \bigg(
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1   & b & c \\
    0   & 1 & 0 \\
    0   & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
\bigg)$.

Am I to show that every element $R_x/I \in R/I$ has a multiplicative inverse, ie:

$R_x/I \cdot (R_x/I)^{-1} =
 \bigg(
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & b & c \\
    0   & 1   & 0 \\
    0   & 0   & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
|a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_5\bigg)
$
by calculating the inverse of $R_x/I$ or is there a simpler way/am I missing
something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider the map $\varphi\colon R\to\mathbb{Z}_5$ defined by
$$
\varphi\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
0 & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a
\end{bmatrix}
=
a
$$
and show it's a surjective ring homomorphism.

Comment: Ok, I did that. And I see that ker$(\varphi) = $I. But I don't see how to use this.

Comment: Should I use that the map $\mu: R/I \to \varphi[R]$, $\mu(a+I) = \varphi(a)$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: @Mathaniel Yes, the homomorphism theorem is the key!

Comment: So if I let $\mu: R/I \to \varphi[R]$ defined by $\mu(x+I) = \varphi(x)$ be an isomorphism and let $\gamma: R\to R/I$ be a ring homomorphism defined by $\gamma(x) = x+I$, then I know that for each $x\in R$ we have $\varphi(x) = \mu \gamma(x)$ So since $\varphi$ is a surjective ring homomorphism and $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field and since $\mu$ is an isomorphism from $R/I \to \mathbb{Z}_5$ any element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ has inverse $x^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ & these correspond uniquely to elements and their inverses in $R/I$ $\to$ any element in $R/I$ has an inverse, and so$\to$ $R/I$ is a field.

Comment: @Mathaniel You already know that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field; any ring isomorphic to it is a field as well.

Comment: Brilliant! You guided me through this and whereas I think I might not master this fully, I've learned a lot! Thank you so much =)